# Storing subcollections (filtered versions of the main collection) inside the collection as cache?

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

Is it good practice to store sub-collections of item X inside a parent collection of item X for caching 'filter-queries' which are performed on the parent collection? *(They won't be used together (as in color AND type).)* Or is it also ok to just Loop over the collection and return the correct entities in a temporary collection?

```
Class ItemCollection : Inherits Collection(Of Item)
    Private _types as New List(Of ItemCollection) //Cache

    Function FilterByType(type) As ItemCollection
        If Not _types.KeyExists(type) Then
            _types.Add(type, New ItemCollection())
            For Each i in Me
                If i.Type = type Then _types(type).Add(i)
            Next
        End If
        Return _types(type)
    End Function

    //Same for FilterByColor(color)
End Class

Class Item
    Public Color = "Blue"
    Public [Type] = "One"
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend keeping it simple to start with and then add caching if testing shows that regenerating the filtered lists is a performance problem.  Besides that, the filtering code can be greatly simplified by using filtering methods built into List or using LINQ extensions.

```
filtered = Me.Where(i => i.Type = type)
```

(I could be off on the exact syntax, I've never done LINQ in VB.NET, I'm a C# guy.)

Comment: I started using LINQ, that fixed a lot of my problems! Very fast indeed